# Definition of an $\mathcal{F}$-twist of an algebra

Tags: algebraic-geometry, definition, lie-groups, lie-algebras, vector-bundles

This discussion comes from [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0501398.pdf).

We are considering a connected reductive group $G/\mathbb{C}$ with a Borel subgroup $B\subset G$ and corresponding Lie algebras $\mathfrak{g},\mathfrak{b}$. Also we have an algebraic curve $Y/\mathbb{C}$ and a $B$-bundle $\mathcal{F}$ on $Y$.

**The authors then introduce $\mathfrak{g}_\mathcal{F}$ as the $\mathcal{F}$-twist of a (Lie) algebra $\mathfrak{g}$. What is the twist of an algebra by a bundle?**

When I hear twist I usually think of twisting invertible sheaves by one another, and have not come across it being used for algebras. Additionally I can't seem to find a definition online anywhere.

Comment: They also use the $\mathcal{F}$-twist of a $G$-module. We could view $\mathfrak{g}$ as the adjoint module $\mathfrak{g}$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde what is the $\mathcal{F}$-twist of a $G$-module here. I have not run into this terminology before so having it spelled out would be appreciated.

Comment: Google "Drinfel'd twists". [This slides](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwj-wdrG14v3AhWW7qQKHaOfA4EQFnoECAMQAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dma.unina.it%2Fncg2012%2Fslides%2FFiore.pdf&usg=AOvVaw00WLuCvpgBqcGfFTE1oK5l) talk about  twists of algebras. I suppose there are better references online (I didn't try). I am only surprised that you say "I can't seem to find a definition online anywhere!" I can't believe this.